# Reverse Geolocation issues

Tags: javascript, html, geocode

**EDIT: Solved, updated with working code. Thank you everyone!**

I have a working reverse geolocation application running in jsFiddle, but I cannot seem to get it to work in a normal environment.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vd3mK/

Local Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>​​
        <script>
        var geocoder;
        function initialize() {

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            codeLatLng();
        }

        function codeLatLng() {     
            var input = document.getElementById("latlng").getAttribute('value');
            var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
            var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng': latlng
            }, function(results, status) {

                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '' + (results[0].formatted_address); + ''
            });
        }
​       </script>   
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">        
        <div id="latlng" value="43.4494152,-80.4881973"></div>

        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the local version runs in my browser it gives me: "â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹".

What causes this? How do I fix it? Thanks!

**WORKING CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>​​
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            function codeLatLng() {
                var input = document.getElementById("latlng").getAttribute('value');
                var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
                var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
                var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng' : latlng
                }, function(results, status) {

                    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '' + (results[0].formatted_address);
                    +''
                });
            }

            function initialize() {

                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                codeLatLng();
            }
       </script>   
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize();">        
        <div id="latlng" value="43.4494152,-80.4881973"></div>

        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Geolaction? Is this a new application you've pioneered to locate milk?

Comment: Indeed. LMFAO. Go me, typos and all.

Comment: I would need to see your full HTML, but I would suspect that you don't have the right encoding set in the header section so that the text returned is being misinterpreted by the browser.

Comment: That is the full HTML. I added the encoding and now nothing shows up at all.

Comment: What browser are you using? I just tested your local code in Chrome and it worked fine. I got "53 King St E, Kitchener, ON N2G 2K6, Canada"

Comment: Try adding  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> to your head section.  That's what the Fiddle page has in its header.

Comment: I have the meta tag in there now, and I am using Chrome as well.

Comment: If you go into settings menu and choose Tools/Encoding, for your page, what does Chrome say?  (Should say UTF-8 or equivalent).

Comment: Can you confirm using console.log that you are getting the correct value back from the service?

Comment: I am getting the right values. I solved the issue however. I needed to have my codeLatLng() before initialize. I think I need more coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the encoding of the page through the meta tag, **but you need to also encode the actual page (*the file*) in UTF-8.**

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helped. I solved the issue though, I had my functions in the wrong order.